# Multiple subcategories IDs use in event search API request in eventbrite API

Tags: php, wordpress, api, eventbrite

I want to get list of events by subcategory ID list in event search API.

Refer below events search API reference, 
https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/endpoints/events/

If I used comma-separated format and send to eventbrite api and get below **error** instead of events list as response in JSON format.

```
Array
(
    [status_code] => 400
    [error_description] => There are errors with your arguments: 3002 - Unknown parameter, 3003 - Unknown parameter, 3004] - Unknown parameter
    [error] => ARGUMENTS_ERROR
)
```

My Request,

```
Array
(
    [location.address] => location.address=Austin
    [categories] => categories=103
    [subcategories] => subcategories=3001,3002,3003,3004
    [formats] => formats=11
    [page] => page=1
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eventbrite API request need to send UTF-8 format instead of special characters,

Change your request like below,

```
Array
(
    [location.address] => location.address=Austin
    [categories] => categories=103
    [subcategories] => subcategories=3001%2C3002%2C3003%2C3004
    [formats] => formats=11
    [page] => page=1
)
```

Use %2C instead of comma(,)

Comment: Thanks @GNANA for this help